# Query job is not working in Dataplex Exploration Workbench

Tags: google-dataplex

I'm not able querying the data over exploration workbench of dataplex, even i have added assets in dataplex zone and that entities are visible in explore tab but after running the simple select * from production1raw.machine_data; query  is not working.

any solution on this?